# how to set separate css to each menu item in the asp menu control

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a menu control like below

**menu1 menu2 menu3 menu4**

how to set separate ccs for each menu?.
menu1--css1
menu2--css2
menu3-css3.. like this

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean different styles for each? or load a different file for each ? How are you creating the menu? Can you post your HTML as well ?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand it correctly,you are preparing 4 css files like

```
.css1
{
}
.css2
{
}
.css3
{
}
.css4
{
}
```

and your menu items are men1 menu2 menu3 menu4, 
for implementing this menu, you must be using repeater in your code so from codebehind, you can append css' <'e.item.itemindex'>' and attach this css to your control.